# Google Analytics: How do I track multiple index files in multiple folders?

Tags: asp-classic, google-analytics

I inherited a lovely vintage Classic ASP site. I am running GA (our Webtrends is out of date) and having an issue. Again, I did not build this, I have been at this job for 3 weeks now and the old guy is long gone.

The problem is the past devs have build the site with many folders having their own index.asp files. For example: /index.asp (root a.k.a. homepage), /example1/index.asp, /example2/index.asp, /example3/index.asp, etc.

So looking at the analytics I show usually 90% of my visitors on "index.asp" (which is set as the home page in settings - it won't let me do /index.asp). I need to figure out how to make the folder show up in the tracking because I am guessing I have at least 50 "index.asp" files.

Comment: I set up a filter [following this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012243?hl=en) and am still seeing 96% of traffic on "index.asp" right now. Going to let it run for a while and see if I can start to see the full URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom parameter for each page (e.g. folder name) in your tracking code:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Comment: Going to look into that. My tracking code is only on 1 file (an include of the header for every page). Do you suspect this will work if I add it to one include, or do I need a custom var on every page?

Comment: You will need it on every page. But you could still use a single include and pass the value via a Javascript variable set on each page. Or write out the ga code via classic asp in a include and set the variable there. (e.g read the folder via FSO and pass it on to Google. )

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the javascript that is currently being used to call ga?

If it uses

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

then it should be sending the full url.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

In which case, you will just need to change your reports to extract that info.

Comment: Yes, my code is as you describe above. I have not dug into the reports too much yet. Just looking at the real time numbers, I might have 60/63 people on "index.asp" but it could be anyone. I am going to read what you posted and get into the reports to see what I can pull out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Still seeing 95% of traffic on index.asp, although I do see some small amounts of traffic on the individual pages (folder1/index.asp, folder2/index.asp) so it seems to be working. I just don't believe that 95% of my traffic never leaves the home page because we have a rather large site with a lot of subsections.